# multiple-language on Github-Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

A long time I don't acess my page http://andeon.github.io/askey/apps/gimp/ so, yesterday I checked that the translations not works more for keyboard pages, there was update on github-pages?

Repository structure : github.com/andeon/askey/tree/gh-pages

```
- |-- _includes/      # Html rendered 
- |-- _layouts/       # Templates of the website
-   |--  dic/         # keyboards translation
- |-- index.html      # Default html file (EN)
- |-- pt              # Portuguese Language files
- |-- (...)
- |-- _config.yml     # Jekyll configuration file
```

The file "_includes/gimp_keyboard.html" use the variable **page.t[page.lang].($variable)** to link the translation in "dic/gimp_en.md" or "dic/gimp_pt.md" etc, that's what translated the tooltips of keys and pop-ups.

Structure of Gimp_en.yml:

```
layout: main_gimp
t:
 en:
  tooltip_esc: "Close Dialogs"
  tooltip_f1: "Help"
```

> ex: gimp_keyboard.html Esc key tooltip:

`<a href="#popup_esc" class="key c27 fn" data-tooltip="{{ page.t[page.lang].tooltip_esc }}"><span>esc</span>`

> And Pop-up key w

`<div id="popup_w" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>{{ site.t.l_popupt[page.lang] }}</h2>
            <a class="close" href="#" onclick="history.back(); return false;">×</a>
                <div class="content">
                    <table class="tftable" border="1">
                        {{ site.t.l_thc[page.lang] }}
                        {{ page.t[page.lang].key_w }}`

*The global translation of variable "site.t.(...)[page.lang]" bound inside _config.yml are working.

I don't have idea how fix it. Maybe it not was smart way to make multiple-language with a trick of "dictionary file" (but here the reason https://github.com/andeon/askey/wiki I need the variables to create an easier way to do translations).

Does anyone have any idea to fix or another suggestion?

I'd used this site for reference for create the page: benoitpatra.com/2014/08/24/organize-a-multilanguage-jekyll-site/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a change between Jekyll **2.x** an Jekyll **3.x** that is now in use at github.

Your language string are in a layout. eg: **gimp.html** has **dic/gimp_en** as layout, which itself has languages strings in his front matter under the `t` key.

With jekyll **2.x**, a layout variable was passed through the template cascade in the **page** variable. You accessed it with `page.t`

Now with jekyll **3.x**, a template variable is passed in the **layout** variable. You access it with `layout.t`

If you replace all your `page.t` occurrences by `layout.t`, the magic will happen again.

**Side note** : You can centralize all your language strings in data files. English strings in **_data/lang/en/gimp.yml** and Portuges in **_data/lang/pt/gimp.yml** and access them with `site.lang[page.lang]`.

And you can then remove the intermediary **dic/gimp_xx layout**.

This will be more future proof.